# Export HTML to Word Doc with continuous line number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, ms-word

I am trying to export HTML content - Table + paragraphs with multiple line breaks.
I want HTML content to export in word doc with Auto line numbers in word document.
I do not want it to generate in code by using loops or any other way. I want it to auto set by word doc.

I have tried below code in PHP :

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:sectPr');
$objWriter->startElement('w:lnNumType');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:countBy', '1');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:restart', 'continuous');
$objWriter->endElement();
```

I have added above code in Document.PHP under function _writeEndSection() after $borders = $_settings->getBorderSize(); in PHPWord Library and its working fine.

Can I do it in JavaScript by using XML code or mso-element tags and attribute?
I have used below code but its not working for me.

```
  function exportHTML(){
           var header = '<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"'+
        'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"'+
        'xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"'+
        'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"'+
        'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'+
        '<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>'+
    
    '<xml>'+
            
            '<w:WordDocument>'+
            '<w:View>Print</w:View>'+
            '<w:Zoom>75</w:Zoom>'+
            '<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>'+
            '</w:WordDocument>'+
            '<w:sectPr>'+
            '<w:lnNumType w:countBy=1 w:restart=continuous >'+  
            '</w:sectPr>'+
            '</xml>'+
            '</head>'+  
            '<body style="font: Arial">';
    
    var tblNew = 'TableData';
    var footer = "</body></html>";
    
    var sourceHTML = header+tblNew+document.getElementById("source-html").innerHTML+footer;
        
            var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
            var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
            fileDownload.href = source;
            fileDownload.download = 'testfile.doc';
            fileDownload.click();
            document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this requirement? Thank You in advance.

Comment: The last string in `var header` is missing its double quote `"`.

Comment: @ Kim Hallberg I have changed my code but its still not working...

Comment: In XML attribute-values need to be inside single or double quotes. So use: <w:lnNumType w:countBy="1" w:restart="continuous" >

Comment: @ Siebe Jongebloed  I have changed this and rechecked but still not working.